# From compact width to any width

Tags: xcode6, autolayout, size-classes

I developed my whole app on Xcode 6. I use auto layout on an Universal Storyboard. During the whole development my Storyboard was in the `any height/compact height` size class.

Therefore, now that I'm testing on iPad, i have blank sheet. Same if I put my storyboard back on any width, any height mode, it's all blank.

I think it's linked to the size classes and my views are not implementing all the classes as I added them when I was working in any height/ compact width mode.

So is there any way to move my app back into the `any height/any width` class?

Thank you.